# Light ide for android development

Tags: java, android, windows, ide

Now I'm using IntelliJ Idea. But my notebook has only **2Gb RAM** and Idea is very slow sometimes. I want to have little IDE for education projects. There is AIDE, which run on Android devices, but I want something like AIDE on Windows for simple coding.

Comment: have you tried eclipse?

Comment: Have you tried Eclipse ADT? I used to have 2gb ram... and it worked fine.. :/

Comment: Yes, of course) It ss too monstrous. And I don't like its design. So, sometimes it's slow, too.

Comment: moreover, idea is too intelligent, I would not trade it for eclipse:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[jEdit](http://www.jedit.org) is a lightweight Java IDE, you'll need to install some plugins to use for android development. See here for a small tutorial on this: http://ashish-yadav.blogspot.nl/2012/09/android-development-using-jedit-part-1.html

**But developing Android apps isn't very easy like in Eclipse or IntellijIDEA. Debugging possibilities in jEdit are not remotly as good as these two.**

**Note:** You can use the android tools to set up a project, use any plain text editor to edit java sources and use ant to compile everything and adb to install to the emulator.

This will require some further knowledge on compilen and installing with adb manually though.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html

I would stick with Eclipse or IntellijIdea if I were you, while slower I think you get more good than bad at the end.

**Note 2:** If your biggest point is the slowness of the emulator, well that's tough the emulator is slow on even the heaviest of machines. [You can run a x86 system image as emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration), but I doubt your laptop will handle this.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. I will try. Projects that need to debug, I  still going to do in the idea

Comment: Personally I think using something as jEdit will frustrate you more, but good luck ;)

Comment: use field bord androidtool from sourceforge this will be light weight , also you can achieve code completion using vim editor and vim-android plugin